# put method doesn't update model in database nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Have code without error in console, but field 'check' doesn't change on true state...why?

```
apiRoutes.put('/intake/:id', function(req, res)  {
  var id = req.params.id;
  Intake.findById({id, function(err, intake) {
      if (err)res.send(err);
        check: true;
        intake.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error'});}
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful update check state.'});
    });
  }})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
check: true
```

should be

```
intake.check = true;
```